# Javascript Accessing Local Executables

Tags: javascript, executable

The site http://combatarms.nexon.net/ has a button on the right side 'Start Game'. If you have the game installed on your computer and you are logged into the site, when you click on the button, it will launch the game on your computer.

How is this possible? I was always led to believe that Javascript isn't able to access anything other than the browser itself because this would be a security issue, so how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Amir is almost right, but it seems that they are not registering a protocol but a MIME type, and using an ActiveX (for IE) and a browser pluging for Firefox and other browsers:

From http://combatarms.nexon.net/JS/NGM.js:

```
this.strGameAXName = "NXCOM.NxGameControl.US.2"; // ActiveX class
this.strGameFPName = "application/x-npnxgame-us"; // MIME type
this.strNxMInfoAXName = "NXCOM.NxMachineControl.US.1"; // ActiveX class
this.strNxMInfoFPName = "application/x-npnxminfo-us"; // MIME type
```

In summary, since you say that this only works when the game is installed, it seems that they are using the same method that, for example, Adobe Reader or Quicktime: installing a browser plugin/activex and registering a MIME type that is associated with that plugin.

The only difference is that they use javascript (you can use any plugin from JavaScript, for example you can control Windows Media Player plugin or Flash using JS).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the way, but in the old days what most applications did was register a protocol that they listened on. So Aim had aim:// and winamp://. The operating system then handles these protocols and passed them to appropriate application. I am curious if its the same thing here.

Ok what ever it is, seems to be in this file.
http://combatarms.nexon.net/JS/NGM.js

Edit ahhh :)

```
var NGMModuleInfo = '<?xml version="1.0"?><NGMModule><NGMDll host="ngm.nexon.net/ngm/NGM/Bin/NGMDll.dll" crc="1505415642" /><GameData><combatarms_us gamecode="33563143" crc="0" /></GameData></NGMModule>';
```

So its a dll file that is being used. So most likely an ActiveX or something similar. Probably doesn't work on a mac :)

Comment: Yeah, the game is Windows only.